# Why does pandas join with mis-sorted multiindex give stack overflow?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, join

When joining two pandas dataframes with MultiIndex that are not "in order", my pandas installation makes python crash with error code 0xC00000FD. It took me a while to find my bug, and when I found it I got even more confused. Why did this happen, and how should I get better at spotting it?

Consider the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    ("foo", 1, .1),
    ("foo", 2, .2),
    ("bar", 1, .3),
    ("bar", 2, .4)
], columns=["Level1", "Level2", "Value"])


df2 = df.set_index(["Level1","Level2"])
df3 = df.set_index(["Level2","Level1"])

combination = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print("ok")
combination2 = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print("fail")
```

It gives the following output:

```
  Level1  Level2  Value
0    foo       1    0.1
1    foo       2    0.2
               Value
Level1 Level2       
foo    1         0.1
       2         0.2
               Value
Level2 Level1       
1      foo       0.1
2      foo       0.2
ok
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

The problem arose when I had a table, made some pivots/melts, and wanted to go back to the original multiindex and join my results. At first I did not understand the error message. From [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/52xewh/need_help_with_0xc00000fd/) I learned that the error code is a stack overflow. From [this PR to pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21541) I learned that the recursion is somehow related to calculating group indices. This information made me able to hunt down my bug and also create a minimal reproducing example.

Now to my question:

- Why does this happen? Shouldn't Pandas give some more informative error? My intuition says that it should be easy to spot.
- Is there any way to programatically identify these errors instead of finding yourself with a stack overflow, uninformative errors and a broken debugger?

**EDIT** The error as stated occurs in the latsest python and pandas to date, pandas 0.24.2 and python 3.7.3

Comment: I get the following error when I run your code : " merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented". The error message seems pretty straightforward

Comment: Nice. I'd love to get that error message. What version of pandas and python are you running? I use pandas 0.24.2 and python 3.7.3.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.21.1 and Python 3.6.5

Comment: It is strange that your older version fails with more grace. It sounds like a regression bug then...

Comment: Yes it's weird..

Comment: As a future comment: running the code in a PyCharm Python terminal gives the error 0xC00000FD. Copy paste of the code above into the Python REPL gives an explicit "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded", which is nicer, but still gives no hint about the actual error.